# How to convert $(A \vee B) \wedge (C \vee D)$ to CNF?

Tags: logic, conjunctive-normal-form

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) states that all propositional logic statements can be transformed into CNF.

However, I'm not so sure how we can further simplify $(A \vee B) \wedge (C \vee D)$?

Or if this is CNF, why is it in CNF? To quote wikipedia:

> ... it is a conjunction of one or more clauses, where a clause is a disjunction of literals; otherwise put, it is a product of sums or an AND of ORs ...

Comment: It is already in CNF.

Comment: @player3236 can you explain why? I've edited the post to reflect the definition: each clause should contain disjunctions and each clause should be conjunction'd with each other.

Comment: Both $A\lor B$ and $C\lor D$ are clauses. You have conjunction'd them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A \vee B) \wedge (C \vee D)$ is an AND of two OR's: $A \vee B$ and $ C \vee D$

Moreover, both OR's are disjunctions of literals: $A, B, C,$ and $D$ are all atomic statements, which are all literals.

So, this statement is in CNF